# Properties about gcd and lcm

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

The gcd of (a ,b,c) can be represent by (a,b,c) . Lcm of (a,b,c) can be represent by [a,b,c] 
    Show that $$\frac {[a,b,c]^2}{[a,b][b,c][c,a]} = \frac{(a,b,c)^2}{(a,b)(b,c)(c,a)}$$
   I start the problem but I had no idea to start please help me to solve this problem